# can anyone annotate the code?

Tags: javascript, html, function, annotations

this is my code 
what are the assets in this code ?
and :    explain where the assets will be best located 
    Describe the structure of an array that could be used to handle the traffic light sequence.

Write a script that uses the array described  to produce an animation of a set of traffic lights such that the lights change in the standard sequence each time the button is clicked

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
<head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head> 
<script>
i=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

    if(i==1){   
    document.getElementById("tf1").setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    document.getElementById("tf2") .setAttribute("fill", "yellow");
        i=2;
     }else if (i==2){
    document.getElementById("tf2").setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    document.getElementById("tf3") .setAttribute("fill", "green");
    i=3;
      } else if(i==3) {
    document.getElementById("tf3").setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    document.getElementById("tf1").setAttribute("fill", "red") ;
        i=1;
    }       

    });
});

</script>


<title>Traffic Light</title> 
</head>
<div  style="width:100px;height:360px;border:3px solid #000;"> 
<button>Change Lights</button> 
 <svg height="100" width="100"> 
 <circle id=tf1 cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"fill="red"/></svg> 
 <svg height="100" width="100"> 
 <circle id="tf2" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"fill="transparent"/></svg> 
 <svg height="100" width="100"> 
 <circle id="tf3" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"fill="transparent"/></svg>  

</div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

i also need to write a detailed annotation of every single line, i have done the bottom bit i just need help with this section. can anyone help me annotate just this bit of the code in deatil?:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head> 
<script>
i=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

    if(i==1){   
    document.getElementById("tf1").setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    document.getElementById("tf2") .setAttribute("fill", "yellow");
        i=2;
     }else if (i==2){
    document.getElementById("tf2").setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    document.getElementById("tf3") .setAttribute("fill", "green");
    i=3;
      } else if(i==3) {
    document.getElementById("tf3").setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    document.getElementById("tf1").setAttribute("fill", "red") ;
        i=1;
    }       

    });
});

</script>
```

help will be great

Comment: That isn't what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Why exactly do you need help? Is there something you don't understand? (then ask for that instead (although, if you don't understand it, how did you write the code)). Or is it just too much writing for you? (that's not what SO is for).

Answer (score -2):

You are not using proper method to for attribute. Used **attr()** to change attribute style.

Try this :

```
<div  style="width:100px;height:360px;border:3px solid #000;"> 
<button>Change Lights</button> 
 <svg height="100" width="100"> 
 <circle id=tf1 cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"fill="red"/></svg> 
 <svg height="100" width="100"> 
 <circle id="tf2" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"fill="transparent"/></svg> 
 <svg height="100" width="100"> 
 <circle id="tf3" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"fill="transparent"/></svg>  

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
i=1;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("button").click(function(){

    if(i==1){   
    jQuery("#tf1").attr("fill", "transparent");
    jQuery("#tf2") .attr("fill", "yellow");
        i=2;
     }else if (i==2){
    jQuery("#tf2").attr("fill", "transparent");
   jQuery("#tf3") .attr("fill", "green");
    i=3;
      } else if(i==3) {
    jQuery("#tf3").attr("fill", "transparent");
    jQuery("#tf1").attr("fill", "red") ;
        i=1;
    }       

    });
});
```

Here is Jsfiddle code Link : https://jsfiddle.net/dex0xpcL/

Comment: OP is asking for writing annotations, not versions of the code that use jQuery. Also _"You are not using proper method to for attribute"_ the code is using the DOM method [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) so they were using it correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/jLvfxdm4/

Comment: thanks a lot but I know that I'm not using it properly, I have to leave it like that and just explain what every line does in the code  in detail.